# redirect index to another page with address bar unchanged

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have a page at [www.domain.com/subfolder/somepage.php](http://www.domain.com/subfolder/somepage.php) and I need [www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com) to route to it without changing the address displayed on the address bar.

I have tried `Redirect /index.php /subfolder/somepage.php`
but the address bar will be changed as well.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can load the file using php.

```
<php 
require_once '/subfolder/somepage.php';
?>
```

or proxy it with with htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subfolder/somepage.php [P]
```

Comment: Thanks for this! However [P] didn't work for me, I had to use [L]. May I ask what's the difference?

Comment: The [L] flag causes mod_rewrite to stop processing the rule set. In most contexts, this means that if the rule matches, no further rules will be processed. 

Use of the [P] flag causes the request to be handled by mod_proxy, and handled via a proxy request. 

Source: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html